# Js closures: Function fails during second invoke

Tags: javascript, closures

I have the following example

```
function sum (a){

 this.sum = a;
 this.x  =  function (b){
  if (b == undefined ){
    return sum;
  }else
  {
   sum+=b;
   return x;
  }
 }
 return x;
}
```

It works for such call `sum(1)(2)(3)()` for the first time but fails when i invoke it twice 
can anyone help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use global variables for `sum` and `x`. Declare them as local with var keyword:

```
function sum(a) {
    var sum = a;
    var x = function (b) {
        if (b == undefined) {
            return sum;
        } else {
            sum += b;
            return x;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

sum(1)(2)(3)() // 6
sum(1)(2)(4)() // 7
```

The context (`this`) inside a function in this case is global object, so when the function is executed it sets two global variables, redefining original `sum` function with a number value.

Just remember never use `this` if you deal with a normal function, not a constructor (`new Something()`). That's why it's a good idea to `use strict` mode, then `this` would come as `undefined` and would not lead you to this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you are changing the `sum` after being called.

Your function name is `sum`. When you are saying

```
 sum += b; //you are changing `sum` in a number.
```

That's why next time calling `sum` says `Number is not a function`

And use local variables for `sum` and `x`.